# ASP 4.0 get values from session

Tags: asp.net

im trying to find the contents of the session in a webpage im working on.
But since im not a programmer i have to revert to copy paste code i find online...

I dont know what variables are set in the session, thats why i want to know how many and what variables there are.

Now i found the following

```
<font face=arial size=1>
Session Variables - <% =Session.Contents.Count %> Found<br><br>
```

This works like a charm. It finds 7 to 12 values in the session. But when i try to follow up WHATS inside the session...

```
    <%
Dim item, itemloop
For Each item in Session.Contents
  If IsArray(Session(item)) then
    For itemloop = LBound(Session(item)) to UBound(Session(item))
%>
<% =item %>  <% =itemloop %> <font color=blue><% =Session(item)(itemloop) %></font><BR>
<%
    Next
  Else
%>
<% =item %> <font color=blue><% =Session.Contents(item) %></font><BR>
<%
  End If
Next
%>
```

my page crashes with: CS1044 (and the dutch translation)
Since part 1 worked of the code i assumed that part 2 would work too.

Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that i needed to use Visual Studio 2015 (community edition) to find my answer for at least part of the question.

Hightlighting the string with what seemd to be a session variable (user.firstname) took me to user.cs (using F12) where i could find the other variables.

Hope this helps someone...